# HEX to String and back - value not matching

Tags: java, hex, data-conversion

I am trying to convert a hexadecimal value to a string and then back to hexadecimal.

I see that for some of the hexadecimal value I get the original value back when I convert the generated string back to hexadecimal, however for some value the value is not matching.

Working example : 414d512044435344454d4f2020202020bc9b72561dda9820

Not Working example : 414d512044435344454d4f2020202020bc9b7256026cb420

I tried from online sites like http://codebeautify.org and from java code (http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-hex-to-ascii-in-java/) as well.

Please help me to understand why I see such a behavior. Thanks in advance.

```
public class StringToHex{

  public String convertStringToHex(String str){

  char[] chars = str.toCharArray();

  StringBuffer hex = new StringBuffer();
  for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
    hex.append(Integer.toHexString((int)chars[i]));
  }

  return hex.toString();
  }

  public String convertHexToString(String hex){

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

  //49204c6f7665204a617661 split into two characters 49, 20, 4c...
  for( int i=0; i<hex.length()-1; i+=2 ){

      //grab the hex in pairs
      String output = hex.substring(i, (i + 2));
      //convert hex to decimal
      int decimal = Integer.parseInt(output, 16);
      //convert the decimal to character
      sb.append((char)decimal);

      temp.append(decimal);
  }
  System.out.println("Decimal : " + temp.toString());

  return sb.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  StringToHex strToHex = new StringToHex();

  String hex = "414d512044435344454d4f2020202020bc9b7256026cb420";
  System.out.println("Hex : " + hex);

  System.out.println("\n***** Convert Hex to ASCII *****");
  System.out.println("Hex : " + hex);
  String acsii = strToHex.convertHexToString(hex);
  System.out.println("ASCII : " + acsii);

  System.out.println("\n***** Convert ASCII to Hex *****");
  String str = acsii;  
  System.out.println("Original input : " + str);
  System.out.println("Hex : " + strToHex.convertStringToHex(str));
  }
}
```

Comment: What encoding are you using to perform this conversion? Show some code.

Comment: I tried with the online site which helps the conversion  http://codebeautify.org/string-hex-converter
http://codebeautify.org/hex-string-converter and also tried with the code available at http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-hex-to-ascii-in-java/.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't try to invent wheels. Use some mature library functions like `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.(de|en)code`. Or - for curiosities sake - look at their productive code. Don't expect tutorial code to work without issues (even if mkyong normally has high quality examples). If you insist on doing it this way **SHOW YOUR CODE**.

Comment: Tried it. I get the correct result. Because your string contains some special characters I suspect that your problem may be encoding or locale related. Tested it on a linux maschine clean configured for utf-8. Maybe you should start with some "not so special" characters to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote the code to convert the String to Hexadecimal as

```
  public String convertStringToHex(String str){

  char[] chars = str.toCharArray();

  StringBuffer hex = new StringBuffer();
  for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
    hex.append(String.format("%02x", ((int)chars[i])));
  }

  return hex.toString();
```

}

and now it works correctly. The problem seems to that earlier it was ignoring the leading zero in the hexadecimal.

Comment: Now it makes sense to me.